# In Python, run a version of a script by specifying its git commit hash

Tags: python-3.x, git, github

Let's say I have a Python script called `example.py` which I've committed to git several times. Now what I want is to have a different script called `run_example.py` which relies on the first script and takes as a command-line (or configurable) argument the commit SHA hash of `example.py` it should use, e.g.

```
python run_example.py <desired SHA of example.py>
```

and thus by specifying a different commit hash, a different version of `example.py` would be referenced and run.

What's the cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: You'd need to call a subprocess to check out a version of the file, or have a native python interface to git. Either way, you are likely looking for a third party tool.

Answer (score 1):

One option: make a temporary version of your script at the desired revision, then delete it when finished:

```
$ git show <desired SHA>:example.py > tmp-example.py
$ python run_example.py tmp-example.py
$ rm tmp-example.py
```

Comment: I wrote a demo and tried `git show <desired SHA>:example.py | python`, and it worked. But not sure if it's okay for all cases.

Comment: Cool! I guess that could be a little risky in some cases. If it works for you, let me know and I’ll update the answer.